# delay between cronjobs in debian

Tags: ubuntu, cron, debian

At the moment i run 7 scripts at the same time via cronjob.

This is how my crontab-file looks like:

```
0 */2 * * * python3 /my/path/script1.py > /my/path/cronlog.txt
0 */2 * * * python3 /my/path/script2.py > /my/path/cronlog.txt
0 */2 * * * python3 /my/path/script3.py > /my/path/cronlog.txt
0 */2 * * * python3 /my/path/script4.py > /my/path/cronlog.txt
0 */2 * * * python3 /my/path/script5.py > /my/path/cronlog.txt
0 */2 * * * python3 /my/path/script6.py > /my/path/cronlog.txt
0 */2 * * * python3 /my/path/script7.py > /my/path/cronlog.txt
```

Now the problem is they are running at EXAKT the same time. But i need a delay of more or less 30 seconds between each cron.

Is it possible to build something like `/etc/cron.hourly` would do? I don't mind if script1.py runs at exakt 2pm or 2.30pm. It is only necessary to run it every 2 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running all of them at 0 minutes, you could run them at different minutes?

```
0 */2 * * * python3 /my/path/script1.py > /my/path/cronlog.txt
1 */2 * * * python3 /my/path/script2.py > /my/path/cronlog.txt
2 */2 * * * python3 /my/path/script3.py > /my/path/cronlog.txt
3 */2 * * * python3 /my/path/script4.py > /my/path/cronlog.txt
4 */2 * * * python3 /my/path/script5.py > /my/path/cronlog.txt
5 */2 * * * python3 /my/path/script6.py > /my/path/cronlog.txt
6 */2 * * * python3 /my/path/script7.py > /my/path/cronlog.txt
```

Comment: Haha too easy ... didn't see that. But is there a possibility to run it like randomly?

Comment: Hmm if that is a requirement then I would probably consider just writing another python script that runs each of the other scripts in random order, and will wait for one script to finish before running the next one? Then put that new script in the crontab instead?